# How to fix my own version of tr function?

Tags: c

Im working on a simplified version of the tr function, the structure is as follows:

mytr char1 char2 file1 file2.

For now the only function I want to make is to substitute the char1 in file1 to the char2 in file2. As of now i am only able to copy the content of file1 in file2, but the characters don't change. I've set the names of the functions in spanish, so here are the translations: Abrir -> Open ; Cerrar -> Close; Leer -> Read; daerror -> shows the message of how the implementation should be.

I know i haven't used the Leer function, but i wasn't 100% sure if it was right so i just used the read one.

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <string.h>

int Abrir(char* nombre)
{
    int result;
    result=open(nombre,O_RDONLY);
    return result;

}

int Cerrar(int fd){
    if(close(fd)==-1){
      fprintf(stderr,"error al cerrar el fichero\n");
      exit(-1);
    }
}

char Leer(int fd){
  char car;
  int nbytes;
    nbytes=read(fd,&car,sizeof(char));
    if(nbytes==-1){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error en la lectura del fichero\n");
    exit(-1);
    }
    if(nbytes==0){
      return car;
      // car='\0';
    }
    return car;
}

void daerror(){
    printf("Utilizacion funcion: mitr caracter1 caracter2 fichero1 fichero2 <Cambia los caracteres de 1 en 2 y lo pone en el fichero2>\n");
}

void main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int arch2;
    if(argc>0){
            char* cadena1=argv[2];
            char* cadena2=argv[3];
            char* ficheroabrir=argv[4];
            char* ficherocrear=argv[5];
            int arch1=Abrir(ficheroabrir);
            int arch2=Abrir(ficherocrear);
            char c;
            if(arch1==-1){
                printf("no existe el fichero origen");
                exit(-1);
            }else if(arch2==-1){
                printf("entra aqui");
                                int fd2 = open(ficherocrear,O_WRONLY|O_CREAT,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
                while(read(arch1,&c,sizeof(c)!=0)){

                    if(c!=*cadena1){
                    write(fd2,&c,sizeof(c));

                    }else{
                        write(fd2,&cadena2,sizeof(char));
                    }
                }   
                Cerrar(fd2);
                Cerrar(arch1);
                exit(0);
            }


    }else{
        daerror();
    }

}
```

My output just puts the content of file1 in file2, but doesn't make the changes of char1 to char2

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to account for your trouble, but this line

```
while(read(arch1,&c,sizeof(c)!=0))
```

should be

```
while(read(arch1,&c,sizeof(c))!=0)
```

or even better

```
while(read(arch1, &c, 1) == 1)
```

which will also catch `-1` returned.

Note too that

```
write(fd2,&cadena2,sizeof(char));
```

should be

```
write(fd2, cadena2, 1);
```

because `cadena2` is already a pointer.

---

You have the use of program arguments incorrect, judging from your "Utilizacion" output:

- `argv[1]` character 1
- `argv[2]` character 2
- `argv[3]` file name 1
- `argv[4]` file name 2

and you must check `argc` for the exact number of arguments expected.

Comment: Thanks! The second change actually made the program work, but there is a problem. If i want to change for example the letter "a" for an "bc" it won't work, it will just switch the a to the b because of the 1 in the parameter of write

Comment: OIn that case `write(fd2, cadena2, strlen(cadena2));`

Comment: wow completely forgot about using strlen, thank you very much! :)

Comment: I've encountered another problem. if i try to change more than 1 character, for example, "hello" for another string like "world", it will only change the h of hello for world